# jQuery jqModal Ajax and nested modal problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqmodal

I just started using jqModal as I need support for nested modals.  I'm noticing some erratic behaviour with nested modals and AJAX, but I don't know exactly how to fix it.  What happens is when I load the main modal, that has a nested modal in it, I get two jqmOverlay divs, it's like it's applying the overlay for both modals, even though the nested one hasn't been triggered yet. So when I close the modal, there's still one overlay being displayed.  Here's the code:

```
// Main Modal
$(function(){
  $("#modal").jqm({ajax:'@href'});
});
<a class="label jqModal" href="/suppliers/2/edit">View Supplier</a>


// Nested Modal code fragment within the /suppliers/2/edit html
$(function(){
  $("#nested_modal").jqm({ajax:'@href', zIndex:3001});
})
<a class="button jqModal" href="/suppliers/6/bills/new">Add Bill</a>
```

It seems to work the first time, but if I close the main modal, then open again I get the double overlay problem. Is this a bug? or the way I'm calling my nested modal?  Also, I know it has to do with the nested modal, because when I remove the jqm call on the nested modal, the main modal works fine every time.

Comment: Could it be that you're not closing the nested modal correctly? Are you using a custom 'close' function? The jqmOverlay div should be destroyed in the DOM every time you close.

Comment: I'm using the standard <a class="jqmClose" href="#">Cancel</a>

Comment: I think anyway it's more important to find out why two overlays are created.  I can see them both being appended in firebug.  Also, since two overlays have opacity 50% I can actually see a difference in overlay bg colour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar problems with my nested AJAX jqModals. Here's the solution: the **toTop** parameter, combined with **z-index**.

Set a high **z-index** of your nested modal, and then set **toTop** to true when creating the JQM. For example:

```
// Nested:
<div id="test" style="z-index: 5000;">Test content</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ready(function(){
    $('#test').jqm({
    toTop:                  true,
    modal:                  true,
    overlay:                10,
    });
});
</script>
```

Messing around with the **z-index** and the **toTop** parameter should help in solving your problem.

Comment: Thx for the response.  I'll hopefully get a chance to play around with this soon so I can accept it.

Comment: Worked like a charm, but I seem to be having issues now when I close both modals, the initial modal link opens up twice.  I'll add a new question once I've played around with it more.  Sorry for the delay in acceptance

Comment: Nevermind, it was because I was using the same trigger as the original modal trigger.  adding trigger: '.jqNestedModal' to the jqm initialize and adding the class .jqNestedModal link to all my ajax linked fixed the problem.  Thx again!

Comment: No problem Brad, happy to help!